# Hosting a custom Angular App in the cumulocity

Tags: cumulocity

We are creating a custom Angular[image] App which uses only the services of cumulocity and not any cumulocity based plugins.

If i host this app inside the cumulocity, the app will work or not.

Please clarify. We are needing answers for many question but we don't have until now.

Please help us to support Soon

Thanks
BA

---

After your comments i have created application folder which contains certain assets, index.html etc..

At the end i zipped and uploaded in the tenant. When i clicked the application it is going to 404 not found.

Attached the screen shot for your reference.

https://tempar.adamos.com/apps/custom-app/index.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: To make this question more helpful can you add the error that you are getting (from browser console) and also the file structure that you are uploading. StackOverflow is not a support thread. If you are continuously  updating the original question it is not helpful for other developers that have similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app has no relation to the plugin concept all you need is the application manifest in the ZIP file you are uploading (http://cumulocity.com/guides/web/introduction/).

Also ensure that on root level of the ZIP file there is the index.html

Comment: In that case, my custom application can use any JavaScript framework, node modules, bower, grunt etc. ?

Comment: Yes correct. Just needs to be a single page application.

Comment: Ok Manu, Thanks a lot. Today i will try and put the custom application in the cumulocity and see whether its works or not.

Comment: I have tried to upload the custom-app single page app, but i get 404 error, on clicking the application. Regarding this i have attached the image for your reference. Just want to understand any else i'm missing here or not.

Comment: If you give us an example custom application, which does not depend on the any plugins it will be great.

Comment: You can try out any example SPA like https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/react. Just clone the repo, add the cumulocity.json to root and zip it